# What would stop iTunes from accessing a library stored on a Windows Server?

Tags: itunes, smb

I moved my iTunes library over to a Windows Server SMB share and while I can see, access, change and create new files just fine within the iTunes folder and even rename the `iTunes Library.itl` file from my macOS system, when I try to open this in iTunes I receive the following error:

[image: error]

Any thoughts on what might cause iTunes to have such a problem?

Comment: What do you mean by changing or creating files within the iTunes folder and renaming the .itl file? I'm pretty positive you're not supposed to edit anything in the iTunes folder on the filesystem level.

Comment: In order to verify read-ability by the macOS client to the SMB server, I `touch`'d a new file in the folder, I opened the .xml file to verify access and contents, and simply renamed `iTunes Library.itl` to `iTunes Library.itl.test` and then back to `iTunes Library.itl` - again to verify the capacity to read and write to the contents of this folder such that we know that iTunes and macOS do not have trouble with any access permissions.